# Can't bind ion-range value with ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, range, ionic5

I'm trying to bind the `ion-range` value with the default `[(ngModel)]`, but it doesn't seem to be possible. I declared the `rangevalue` as a `number`, as mentioned in [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v4/api/range#properties). I see that someone already managed to do this with Ionic 5 [(¹)](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-camera-preview-floating-camera-view-in-page-tutorial/) [(²)](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-range-default-value/63977/2?u=leonardofmed) [(³)](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-range-with-selected-value-in-ionic-4/178034/3?u=leonardofmed), but I can't find any difference with my method. Although the `change()` event is triggered each time the range is changed, the same `rangeValue` value is maintained.

*I'm using **Ionic 5** with **Angular 10**.*

What I tried to do:

**HTML FIRST TRY**

```html
<ion-range min="0" max="1" step="0.05" (ionChange)="change()" [(ngModel)]="rangeValue">
    <ion-icon size="small" slot="start" name="sunny"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon slot="end" name="sunny"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

**HTML SECOND TRY**

```html
<ion-range min="0" max="1" step="0.05" (ionChange)="change()" [value]="rangeValue">
    <ion-icon size="small" slot="start" name="sunny"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon slot="end" name="sunny"></ion-icon>
</ion-range>
```

**TypeScript**

```js
private rangeValue: number;

change() {
    console.log('rangeValue: ', this.rangeValue);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5-angular-10-start-template-sfibnx?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/tab1/tab1.page.html) with Ionic 5 and Angular 10, using the **same** code I'm using, but for my frustration at stackblitz it's working as expected. Perhaps there is something interfering with the correct functioning?

Comment: I suposse your variable must be "public" (In Angular if one variable is not public can not be used in the .html)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the problem. In other HTML elements I use `ngModel` with private variables.  I think that what you pointed out is only valid for using the variable on other pages. Even so, I tried to change it to public, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: my bad!! is `console.log(this.valueRange)`, you forgot the `this`

Comment: Actually my bad! In my code I'm already using `this.`, already update in original post.

Comment: this https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-ionic-ion-range-color-dynamically-vvg8ke?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts (I google about stackblitz ionic range and forked) looks like work. Sorry, really I don't know about ionic

Comment: This is very strange and frustrating, I am doing the same thing and the variable is not updating. This is the only component where this occurs. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: Also, the stackblitz you linked is using Ionic 3 and Angular 5, maybe this is the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the way the range element was generated, in this case programmatically with a `*ngFor`. Therefore, `ngModel` was not linked correctly. To solve this issue I used `getElementById()` function, even though I didn't find it interesting to get DOM data without using Angular.

```js
change(programmaticallyGenId) {
    let rangeValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById(programmaticallyGenId)).value;
    console.log(rangeValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ion-range mode="md" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" [(ngModel)]="rangeValue" (ionChange)="change(rangeValue)">
```

TS:

```
public rangeValue: number = 0;

change(range){
    console.log(range)
  }
```